# API versioning: URL path to access the latest version

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, versioning, restful-url

I need to create a mechanism to request the latest version of my API. I know that you can specify a default version, but I don't need this. The purpose is to access to `https://<server>:<port>/api/latest/<controller>`, where `latest` is actually the most recent version. I need to define both versioning options: the major/minor and this one. Below are the two different ways to perform requests:

- `https://<server>:<port>/api/latest/<controller>`
- `https://<server>:<port>/api/v1/<controller>`
- `https://<server>:<port>/api/v1/<controller>`

In the above example, the `latest` would point to the v2.

The difficulty here is that the built-in ApiVersioning from ASP.Net Core (the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` package) doesn't support string named versions since the [ApiVersion](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/master/src/Common/ApiVersion.cs) uses integers for versioning.

Is there any "clean way" to achieve it?

Comment: In the words of Roy Fielding, mastermind behind REST, on the question on how to version URIs he replied with: [`don't`](https://www.infoq.com/articles/roy-fielding-on-versioning/). In short, not the URI is the important bit but the content that is exchanged via URIs and the content may change over time for the same URI. Versioning of URIs has an RPC smell to it actually

Comment: First of all, thanks for sharing that interview. However, Fielding talks about why REST should not use versioning. That doesn't help me for solving the problem I exposed since API versioning it's a requirement.